# GUI Layout of My Text Game

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, jpanel, jbutton

Hi I am trying to work on the GUI of my text based game with a border layout, and I almost have what I am trying to achieve with the GUI.

Here is what I want. I have almost everything down.. besides the Buttons. I want it to look like it does in my sketch.

Can I get any help on how to achieve this?

[image]

Here is my class for setting up the GUI:

```
package Story1;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class textGUI extends JFrame{
    private JButton button;
    private JTextArea plot;
    private JLabel label;

public textGUI()
{
    createView();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400,200));
    setSize(400,200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void createView()
{
    Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    // PANEL
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    //NORTH
    JPanel panelnorth = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(panelnorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panelnorth.add(new JLabel("Chapter 1"));
    //

   //TEXTFIELD CENTER
    JTextArea plot = new JTextArea();
    plot.setLineWrap(true);
    plot.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    plot.setEditable(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(plot);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    //S
    //SOUTH
    JPanel south = new JPanel();
    panel.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JButton button1 = new JButton("HI");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Okay");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("Bye");
    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenSize.width, 10));
    south.add(button1);
    south.add(button2);
    south.add(button3);

    }
}
```

Comment: `BorderLayout` to hold the two main components, a `GridLayout` to hold the "buttons" wrapped in their own component and placed at the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your design a `GridLayout` is likely the best option. In this case the `GridLayout` should have rows set to 0 (which means any number of rows) and columns to 1 (meaning only 1 column) using the constructor `GridLayout(int rows, int cols)`.

Expanding your source code to demonstrate:

```
JPanel south = new JPanel();
south.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
panel.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
JButton button1 = new JButton("HI");
JButton button2 = new JButton("Okay");
JButton button3 = new JButton("Bye");
south.add(button1);
south.add(button2);
south.add(button3);
```

Comment: You're perfect. Thanks!